# Crystal Report: IsNull equivalent for SQL Expression

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports

I want to filter out the data in my crystal report. Currently, I have the following formula in the Record Selection: `isnull({T_TABLE.SOME_COLUMN})`.

Apparently, if we use some functions in Crystal Report, it does not get converted to the SQL query (i.e. it will not add the SQL statement with something like `T_TABLE.SOME_COLUMN IS NULL`.
Since this checking is pretty basic, I want this condition to be pushed to the SQL statement that is generated because it should be faster to filter at database level rather than Crystal Report. Based on what I read, the possible way to push some condition to the SQL statement is to use the `SQL Expression Fields`. But I don't seem to be able to write `T_TABLE.SOME_COLUMN IS NULL`. It gives error : `FROM keyword not found where expected`.

Any idea how to solve this?

[EDIT]: The `IsNull` seems to be pushed when if it is `isnull({T_TABLE.SOME_COLUMN})`. But if it is some view, e.g. `isnull({V_VIEW.SOME_COLUMN})`, it does not get pushed.

Comment: why not try something like this `{T_TABLE.SOME_COLUMN}<>""`

Comment: This should work automatically the way you're doing it, and testing with Crystal Reports XI on SQL Server 2008 shows that `IsNull` does get translated to SQL `IS NULL`. Unfortunately I do not have an Oracle database server available I can test on.

Comment: @Siva: I'm not so sure whether replacing NULL with empty string will be a problem or not for me.

Comment: @hvd: I've just edited my post. It seems to be pushed when it's some table, but not if it is a view. Are you able to confirm from your side about this? Btw I'm using CR 10 with Oracle 8.

Comment: Nope, sorry, still works here when using a view. And just in case, I also tried it with a column where the server already knows it's non-nullable, but it doesn't get optimised out, it still appears in the SQL query I get.

Comment: @hvd I can confirm that this is the way it works in Oracle as well, for tables or views.

Comment: I think I know why it does not get converted. In the record selection, it was written as `isNull({V_VIEW.SOME_COLUMN}) = true`, when I remove `= true` so that it becomes `isNull({V_VIEW.SOME_COLUMN})`, the SQL query I get has ` IS NULL` clause. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IsNull()` function is actually pushed to the SQL query, with the condition that it is not compared to some value in the Crystal Report Record Selection formula.

So `IsNull({T_TABLE.SOME_COLUMN})` is converted to SQL query `T_TABLE.SOME_COLUMN IS NULL`. But `IsNull({T_TABLE.SOME_COLUMN}) = true` won't.